# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, redux-toolkit

i am not able to fix bug

```js
const products = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
```

i am getting the undefind value in console

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Cart = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  console.log('products : ' + products);
  return (
    <>
      <div className='container'>
        {
          products.map((e) =>
            <div className='col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 py-1' key={e.id}>
              <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem", margin: "auto", height: '25rem' }} >
                <img src={e.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{ width: "16rem", height: "14rem" }} />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <p className="card-title">{e.title}</p>
                  <h5 className="card-text">${e.price}</h5>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

this is my cartSlice part

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        add(state, action){
            state.push(action.payload)
        },
        remove(state, action){
            return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
        }
    }
})

export const {add, remove} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

please help me out

in this below code we are getting the value but data is coming undefined

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => {

    const item = useSelector((state)=> state.cart)
    console.log(item);
    const navStyle = { cursor: 'pointer'}
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Link className="navbar-brand" to={'/'}>Navbar</Link>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to={'/'}>Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to={'/cart'}>cart</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <span className="nav-link" style={navStyle} to={'/'}>Count item : {item.length}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: at least one entry in your `products` array is `undefined`

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` `products`?

Comment: i got undefined

Comment: @satyamagrahari: If `products` *itself* was `undefined` then the error would be different.  It would indicate that you're trying to read `.map()` from `undefined`, not read `image` from `undefined`.  Based on the error and code shown, `products` is an array and at least one entry in that array is `undefined`.

Comment: Looking closer... Even if `e` is `undefined` then the error would happen on the previous line when reading `e.id`, *not* when reading `e.image`.  It sounds like there's something else going wrong here and that the code shown may be misleading.  You are encouraged to provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    
    const cartSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'cart',
      initialState: {
        products: [] // Initial state with an empty products array
      },
      reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {
          state.products.push(action.payload);
        }
        // Other reducers can be added here if needed
      }
    });
    
    export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;
    
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        cart: cartSlice.reducer
      }
    });
    
    export default store;
    
    
    import React from 'react';
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
    import { addToCart } from './store'; // Update the path accordingly
    
    const Cart = () => {
      const products = useSelector(state => state.cart.products);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Cart</h2>
          {products.map(product => (
            <div key={product.id}>
              <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
              <h3>{product.title}</h3>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <button onClick={() => dispatch(addToCart(product))}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Cart;
```

Comment: Also try product?.image

Comment: Can you update this answer to clarify (1) what was the problem, (2) what did you change, and (3) how does that solve the problem?  Currently this is a game of "spot the difference and guess".

Comment: when i am trying to apply to your point not fixed 
getting 
Navbar.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')

Answer (score 0):

i was not sending the proper value in onClick{()=> handleClick(item)}
i was not passing item as parameter of handleClick method. That is why it is picking undefined value.
After passing item as parameter code is working fine.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).